# Filters (topology) in teaching

Tags: general-topology, education

I was wondering how popular is the use of filters at a master level?

If you were a student with no acknowledge of the concept, would you start the reading of an interesting book using this concept (provided there is an appendix explaining it)?

Thank you for sharing your points of view.

Comment: For me it makes sense since it is possible to establish a natural paralelism with sequences, which take a main role when describing the metric space

Comment: Master level? I see this stuff in an intro topology course and it is very useful.

Comment: Only read a book about it if it interests you. It is not a common material that every Master student need to know.

Comment: Do you think the use of it is declining in educational purpose? (It seems to me that older teachers - since a part of them learned math from Bourbaki - were more inclined to use it)

Comment: The question is purely opinion based. I don't see how it fits math se. Voting to close.

Comment: @freakish common! Pedagogical questions can be always seen as opinion based! Is that mean we can't ask about educational matters??? Moreover, it is all up to you to answer with detailed, precise facts : number of master degrees using filters, the evolution of it from the 50thies, etc...  I am not sure that you're reaction is healthy for people who wants to learn and understand better math. Next time I will post : "why is  $i^4=1$? what I tried : $i^3=-i$ and I don't now how to finish!"

Comment: @freakish : can you show me what is the "opinion" of my question? Because I don't feel having one.

Comment: @Netchaiev you can ask, just not here. There's nothing unhealthy about it.

Comment: @freakish so, where?

Comment: If you are interested specifically in pedagogy and topology, [Math Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) would be a natural place to ask.  However you should include more details, such as the definition of *filters* to avoid confusion, also known as "context".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience most topological spaces that appear in a module whose focus is not purely topological are metric or otherwise simple enough that using (ultra)filters to describe their properties is overkill. Usually sequences is enough.

Thus you want your topology modules to build up some familiarity with sequences to make them applicable to the non-topology modules. And then it seems like a waste of time to reformulate things as filters and reteach the same material.

While ultrafilters might make a proof of Tychonoff's theorem straightforward, you don't necessarily save time if you have no other reason to cover them.

The main reason I see to use (ultra)filters is they come up somewhere else in the subject matter. For example Boolean algebras, Models, or Stone-Cech compactifications. To understand these things you need to be familiar with filters. And if that understanding is already forthcoming there are no disadvantages to using them to describe the topology as well.